# Updated ubuntu and python version and now it won't recognize datetime module in pycharm

Tags: python, datetime, ubuntu, pycharm

Hello I have updated ubuntu to version 16.04 and came with a new version of python (2.7.11). After the update I reopenned one of my PyCharm django projects and it won't recognize the datetime module. I deleted previous versions of interpreters that were automatically detected by pycharm and re-installed again the one located in

```
/usr/bin/python.
```

But still the error persists. Have you ever met something like this? Importing datetime from shell (python or django) inside or outside pycharm. Autocompletion doesn't show me datetime either in pycharm. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: is it on virtual env?

Comment: No no...it isn't...